# AjaxExtensions and the .NET 4 Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

The working IDE is Visual studio 2010 and the target Framework of the project is .NET4

I get the error `Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not defined`

after adding the ScriptManager component and building the project.

Actually i get the same error type after adding an UpdatePanel too.

The project has a reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.dll`

Could you please tell me what is going on here?

As far as i saw, after creating a new new dummy web-project, i got no error after adding the script manager object on that. (So now i am 100% sure that the error has something to do with the configuration into my project).

By the way if try to add a reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` the IDE crashes!

Comment: Not sure there's enough info here to be able to help. How come you aren't referencing the System.Web.dll from the GAC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the error `Type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not defined` because you actually need a Reference to the `System.Web.Extensions` library, but you probably figured this out already. It seems strange though that your reference to `System.Web` seems to come from your Program Files instead of the GAC. This might be related to the crash you are getting.

Please try this:

- Close Visual Studio
- Open your web application's .csproj file with a text editor (like
  NotePad++)
- Look for the ItemGroup node; this contains your project references
- Change your reference to System.Web to look like this: `Reference Include="System.Web"`
- Add an additional line: `Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions"`
- Save and Close
- Now open your project again in VS and see if it has helped

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing a reference some where. Since you are using vs2010 you could install [Nuget package manager](http://nuget.org/), and use that to add the AjaxControlToolkit.

Nuget will automatically add all the required references (and dependencies if any) to your project. It just makes it alot easier to reference outside assemblies in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your web.config and remove any references to any System libraries. This will make sure that you're getting the versions from the GAC (make sure to make a backup of your web.config first). Better yet try to remove your web.config entirely (backup!). Run the project and you should be prompted to create a new one. Do so and see if you have the same problem.

Edit: Grammar